# Is AXI a good interface for outside communications?

Tags: adc, digital-communications, risc-v

Suppose if we want to get some data from some ADCs, which are placed in a separate chip, and process that data in RISC-V processor. I was looking for an interface to define/use inside the RISC-V chip to receive the data. I found AXI but it seems mainly for on-chip communication. Are there any suggested protocols/commnication interfaces (between RISC-V chip and the other chip) to use for that purpose?

Comment: And where will those ADCs that are supposed to use AXI(-S) come from? Nobody sells them, so I don't understand what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing that limits AXI (probably you mean AXI-S) from being used at the system level.

AXI (not AXI-S) pin count is kind of high as it has separate buses for write, read request and read response (including the addresses there’s a total of five) so it would not be a good choice for an ADC.

Digging in to your application, ADCs by their nature produce data at a constant rate and don't tolerate backpressure, so there's probably no need for handshaking. Your AXI-S interface would literally be just parallel data and a clock. TREADY would be ignored, and TVALID would always be tied high.

That said, if there's a possibility of using a serial interface from the ADC (such as LVDS or 8B/10B serdes) that would save pins. Then on the RISC-V side, use a deserializer then bridge to AXI-S internally.

Using a serial interface reduces the ADC simultaneous switching output (SSO) noise so you could realize better ADC performance.

Answer (score 0):

Using a parallel interface at the board level has the disadvantage that the mis-match between each bit of the data arriving is larger than on a chip, limiting the rate of that interface. I think a much better solution is to add an existing serial interface core (that hacktastical mentioned) like SPI/I2C that comes with a FIFO buffer for managing different transfer rates and acts as a bridge to the AXI bus

Answer (score 0):

No, AXI and Avalon aren't ideal as external interfaces, despite their simplicity.

As @Miron said, these are parallel interfaces, which makes external routing trickier as frequency increases, but that's not the whole issue: these protocols have provisions for returning values in the same cycle, which is something you almost never want in an external interface because it introduces timing requirements for return signals with respect to the launch clock.

For ADC and DAC interfaces, most people use separate control and data interfaces with separate clocking: a slow bidirectional serial protocol like SPI or I²C for control that is clocked by a microcontroller or FPGA, and a fast unidirectional bus for the data that is clocked by the source.

Answer (score -1):

When interfacing a RISC-V processor with external devices like ADCs that are on a separate chip you have several communication interface option to choose from, such as SPI, I2C, UART, and I2S. AXI is used for on-chip communication within FPGAs and SOCs.